# how to achieve remember me functionality in rails 3 devise with a Sign Out option after Logged in to the rails 3 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, devise

### sessions_controller.rb

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])


  if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
    if params[:remember_me]
      cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
    else
      cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
    end
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
  else
    flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
    render "new"
  end
end

def destroy
  cookies.delete(:auth_token)
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
end
```

---

### application_controller.rb

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if 
  cookies[:auth_token]
end
```

---

### user.rb

```
 def generate_token(column)
   begin
     self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
   end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
 end
```

and so on.......
 I have followed the Remember me Part from "Railcasts Episode #274 Remember Me & Reset Password".

Answer (score 0):

configure routes

```
devise_for :users, path: "auth", path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', password: 'secret', confirmation: 'verification', unlock: 'unblock', registration: 'register', sign_up: 'cmon_let_me_in' }
```

and restart server.